# Function x Class Method in typescript

Tags: typescript

I speak better in typescript than in English, so let me show the code:

```js
type FactoryFunction<T> = () => T;

export class Factory<T> {
  public readonly make: FactoryFunction<T>;
  constructor(
    factory: FactoryFunction<T>
  ) {
    this.make = factory;
  }
}

export class SingletonFactory<T> extends Factory<T> {
  private instance: T;

  constructor(
    factory: FactoryFunction<T>
  ) {
    super(factory);
  }

  make = () => {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = super.make(); //ERROR Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.
    }
    return this.instance;
  }
}
```

It does not work, as you can see. So let me try change something:

```js
type FactoryFunction<T> = () => T;

export class Factory<T> {
  constructor(
    factory: FactoryFunction<T>
  ) {
    this.make = factory;
  }

  make(): T; //ERROR Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
}

export class SingletonFactory<T> extends Factory<T> {
  private instance: T;

  constructor(
    factory: FactoryFunction<T>
  ) {
    super(factory);
  }

  make() {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = super.make();
    }
    return this.instance;
  }
}
```

And again, it does not work.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do here. Is there any appropriate way to get this working properly?

Comment: First sample works https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4hgVwHZIJbLYA8AKgHxQC8UAFAJRUUkDcAUKxAB5hrBQIAbOAGdhsRCnSkKAb1ZQoYTACMBeBFFQQ4AE0ICQUALZwA1hABc4pGgw58haWwUJCw4Kkw3UNeQqgAZhK2VvDedrjABMTkfgxy-lDAABZ4wgB0JuZUgcHozlAAvqzFHNy8-EKiUADKeNgA5gIQKNhhkiDSUFzAENg6Yu22XQmKqHgAbnC9UPXucLgQAPxWLOwubh5ekr6JQeGheREOMWRxUKMKwpiQPvsddAWlClnQ1PSMF34KeAG0AIQpNLpObABYICDxb7+IEZUHgt5Qa63TJmCD0AoKYqJLTATCobBJVJw7DzRZPEpAA

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code was outside of the code: At my `tsconfig`, I was setting `target: "es5"`. Checking the tsconfig at the link provided by @aleksey-l 's comment, I change it to `"ES2017"` and it works.
Additionally I make some modifications to my code, if someone was interested, I think it was less verbose:

```
type FactoryFunction<T> = () => T;

export class Factory<T> {
  constructor(
    public readonly make: FactoryFunction<T>
  ) {}
}

export class SingletonFactory<T> extends Factory<T> {
  private instance: T;

  constructor(
    factory: FactoryFunction<T>
  ) {
    super(() => {
      if (!this.instance) {
        this.instance = factory();
      }
      return this.instance;
    });
  }
}
```